# $limit in a scatter and gather query to a sharded collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

```
user.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      age: { $gt: 18 },
      city: { $in: ["chicago", "paris"] }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      last_logged_in: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10000
  }
])
```

If the `user` collection is partitioned into 10 shards, will each shard return `10,000` documents, totalling to `100,000`?

Comment: Did you check the explain plan? An optimized shard key and query will access only one shard.

Comment: You are asking so many questions about sharding. Did you ever consult the documentation and had a look at it? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#limits

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes:

> If the query limits the size of the result set using the `limit()` cursor method, the `mongos` instance passes that limit to the shards and then re-applies the limit to the result before returning the result to the client.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#limits